# Build nested condition with SelectQuery object

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Can I build nested conditions using the `SelectQuery` object?

I want to get:

```sql
select * 
from car 
where ((car.color = 'blue' or car.model = 'Genesis') 
or (car.manufactor = 'ford' and car.color = 'blue'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you inline all conditions / predicates...

... then you can supply them just like that to your `SelectQuery` object:

```
SelectQuery query = ...
query.addConditions( ( CAR.COLOR.eq("blue") .or ( CAR.MODEL.eq("Genesis") ) )
                 .or ( CAR.MANUFACTOR.eq("ford") .and ( CAR.COLOR.eq("blue") ) ) )
```

I've added some whitespace for improved readability

#### If you want to perform dynamic query building...

... Then you can create your predicate in various steps:

```
Condition condition;

condition = CAR.COLOR.eq("blue");
condition = condition.or(CAR.MODEL.eq("Genesis"));
condition = condition.or(CAR.MANUFACTOR.eq("ford").and(CAR.COLOR.eq("blue")));
```

Both approaches are completely equivalent.

Comment: Thanks =). But now I wonder if there is some way to initialize Condition object without explicitly assigning? Something like: Condition condition = new Condition();

Comment: @KhrystynaMakar: Best ask a new question. :-) It will be more useful for future visitors, that way

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Operator.html) now and it looks like you can use the [addConditions](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html#addConditions-org.jooq.Operator-java.util.Collection-) methods with an [OR operator](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Operator.html) to accomplish your nested query.

There are 4 different overloaded methods with addConditions but the last two allow you to supply an operator (in your case OR) and one of those allows you to string together multiple conditions using a supplied operator.

So all you need to do is break apart your nested statements into separate conditions and then link them together with your `addConditions([Collection of Conditions], OR)` statement.