# How to initialize Condition object without explicitly assigning?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

There is some [example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894423/build-nested-condition-with-selectquery-object)

```
Condition condition;

condition = CAR.COLOR.eq("blue");
condition = condition.or(CAR.MODEL.eq("Genesis"));
condition = condition.or(CAR.MANUFACTOR.eq("ford").and(CAR.COLOR.eq("blue")));
```

Is there some way to initialize org.jooq.Condition object without explicitly assigning? Something like:

```
Condition condition = new Condition();
```

And then I want to increment my condition in for-each loop and return this condition object in some method. But if I do:

```
public Condition getRuleConditions(List<Rule> rules){
  Condition condition;
  for(Rule rule: rules){
    condition = condition.or(rule.getField().eq(rule.getValue()));
  }
return condition;
}
```

I can't return this Condition object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Using an initial dummy `Condition`:

```
Condition condition = DSL.falseCondition();
for (Rule rule : rules) {
    condition = condition.or(rule.getField().eq(rule.getValue()));
}
```

#### Using `null`:

```
Condition condition = null;
for (Rule rule : rules) {
    Condition c = rule.getField().eq(rule.getValue());
    condition = (condition == null) ? c : condition.or(c);
}
```

In the second example, the resulting `Condition` can be `null`, of course, and you'll have to handle that elsewhere in the code. In the first example, the resulting `Condition` will never be `null`